# how to compile text-to-speech festival voice free library on win32 with VC

Tags: c++, free, text-to-speech

i need to embed text-to-speech into my application with human void not robotic
i found about festival lib that seams good the only problem is after reading the docs
im not sure if its working on windows or not ?
did someone manage to compile the lib on windows without sygwin

Comment: found it http://e-guidedog.sourceforge.net/doc_build_win_festival.php

Answer (score 0):

Use flite http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/
It's easy to compile on win32 or iOS.